# How do I get back deleted files after running git reflog then git reset HEAD@{1}?

Tags: git, github, git-svn

I messed up with git after running `git reset --hard HEAD~3` and lost 2 hours worth of work. I then found a post on here that explained git reflog.

When I want to return to "`git reset HEAD@{1}`", how do I not only return, but have all files that were removed put back in their directories?

Comment: On Stack Overflow it is not necessary, or recommended to use salutations, valedictions or signatures in questions and answers. In other words, you shouldn't say "I would like help", or "Thanks", because that is why you are here, and we are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to move the branch that you want to be at that point with

`git branch -f master HEAD`

The above example moves the branch `master` to HEAD.  So it requires HEAD to be at the point you want to move the branch to.  If that isn't the case you can use the commit hash or reflog entry instead of HEAD.

If you never commited the files before the `--hard` reset, the work is gone.  Git will only be able to recover what you commited.

Comment: I only use one branch and that's master. So your response is all I would need to type?

Comment: So git branch -f master HEAD@{1} ? Should do the trick? or git branch -f master 6a4034b  ?

Comment: Yes, but that point changes every time head moves, so if you already did `reset HEAD@{1}`, that value will have moved already.

Comment: Yea, I re-checked using reflog. Anyway running above gives me this error: Cannot force update the current branch

Comment: That means you have that branch checked out and are trying to move it out from under yourself.  Since that is the case,  you could always do `git reset --hard HEAD@{1} and accomplish the same thing.